# Push Notification issues iOS 10 - Notification has no user-facing content

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

We're facing several issues with push notifications on iOS 10.
The main problem is that registered devices are not receiving push notification in iOS 10 if the **aps** json value is empty.
There is one case in our app in which the server sends the push without the **aps** value populated since we don't need any alert/title/sound, but i think that it's causing the problem on iOS 10 (no issues in iOS 8/9).

I've installed the PersistentConnectionLogging profile as suggested by Apple ([link here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html)) to see more logs during the communication between iOS and the APNS.
When the push without the **aps** value arrive i can see this log:

```
Sep 26 11:11:52 Mat apsd(PersistentConnection)[86] Notice: 2016-09-26 11:11:52 +0200 apsd[86]: APSCourier: 0x1003127d0: Received message for enabled topic ‘com.app.bundleId’ with payload '{
    aps = {};
    action = init;
}
Sep 26 11:11:52 Mat SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[57] <Error>: Ignoring notification with no content (com.app.bundleId): C2E3-4A9E
Sep 26 11:11:52 Mat SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[57] <Info>: Not saving push notification to store C2E3-4A9E, error=Error Domain=UNErrorDomain Code=1401 "Notification has no user-facing content" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Notification has no user-facing content}
```

It seems that the error logged is [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unerror.code/2196947-notificationinvalidnocontent), but i can't understand if the problem is with the empty **aps** Json value or not.

Does anyone had a similar issue or know if in iOS 10 the **aps** value must be populated with some alert/badge/sound in order to receive the push notification correctly?

ps: the app is on AppStore and was created with Xcode 7 based on the iOS 9 SDK; users that have upgraded to iOS 10 are facing this issue.

Comment: This is definitely a grey area without clear resolution. Carrying multiple streams of code to manage the myriad of push requirements is the most time-consuming portion of complex app development for the iPhone. I am struggling to correct this other than finding that an in-background app is ok, but an "off-app" is dead to the notifs being sent silently when minimalist payloads are present.

Comment: I'm seeing this on iOS 11 as well.